# Firebase function deploy error cannot find module firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to deploy a function to firebase. I've used this tutorial. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
[image]

My package.json is this.

```
    {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And my index.js is this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});
```

Can you tell me whats wrong in the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine it is a firebase cloud functions issue.

I already solved in:

[issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824281/cannot-find-module-firebase-admin-when-trying-to-deploy-firebase-functions/46824464#46824464)

fwd:
Same issue here. It is a firebase problem.

There is disruption in firebase cloud service since yesterday.

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4NMo.png)

problem description: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/17024

**problem solution:**

Run the following commands inside the functions repository:

```
npm install --save-exact firebase-functions@0.7.0 npm install --save-exact firebase-admin@5.4.0
```

Then try deploying functions again:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Wow it worked. You are life saver. Thanks very much.